# PHP preg_match Everything Between Slashes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need the help of a regex wizard, or someone who knows more about this than me (which means there's lots of candidates :)

I am trying to match everything that occurs between the first and second slash, excluding those slashes, or nothing if there's no starting and trailing slash:

```
$subject = '/1234-abcd/blahblah';
$pattern = '/^\/(.*)\//';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Here are the results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /1234-abcd/
    [1] => 1234-abcd
)
```

I'm close. $matches[1] has the result I'm after, but it's not matching this as its first array item (and instead, the first captured subpattern).

How do I exclude the starting and trailing slashes in this regex pattern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
$pattern = '#(?<=/)[^/]+#';
```

And use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`

**PS:** Note that you can also use `explode` to split your input by `/` and avoid using regex altogether.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This pattern matches everything following a slash, similar to if using `explode` delimited by the `/`. Instead, is it possible to capture the first occurrence between just the first and second slash, using regex?

EDIT: Nevermind! I was seeing those results using `preg_match_all`. When using `preg_match`, it's exactly as I need. Thanks so much!!

Comment: For that you can use: `preg_match('#(?<=/)[^/]+#', $input, $m); echo $m[0];`